# Want to exclude distinct values that relate to a value in another column of the table in sql

Tags: sql

I'm not sure I can do this in sql but the problem I'm running into is that I have one column which has names that relate to many values in another column. What i'm trying to do is only show names that do not relate to one of the values in the other column. I can't just exclude that value because the name appears in multiple rows. Is there a way to do this or do I need to use something like Python? Thanks in advance?

| Names | Values |
| --- | --- |
| ps1234 | value 1 |
| ps1234 | value 2 |

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data that illustrates what you want to do.  (3) Show the results. you want from your query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and t2.value = ?
                 );
```

The `?` is a parameter placeholder for the value that you want no names for.

Comment: So I'm new to sql but I can see there is a subquery in your code. What I dont understand is the t and t2. All of my data should be coming from the same table in the database. Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: @drift97 . . . `t` is the name of your table, which your question fails to mention.  `t2` is a table alias.